# OpenCV 2.4.6 Windows 7 Visual Studio 2012 64 bit installation error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Opencv in my 64 bit computer and VS2012. 
I did as this guy in the video says which is in my opinion a great explanation but I get an error which says Module machine type 'x64' coflicts with target machine type 'x86'.

So I tried changing 'x64' to x86 in additional library dictionaries , this time I get dll errors but I added those libraries that it gives error.

So is there anyone who solved this 64 bit problem in OpenCV can help?
Thank you.

Edit:
Now its building it in release mode but I have 
OpenCVProject.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b). Error

Comment: Install a 32 bit version of opencv for visual studio 2012 if you intend on building 32 bit applications.

Comment: my vs2012 is 64 bit so isn't it gonna make a problem installing opencv 32 bit ?

Comment: Visual Studio x64 will build 64 or 32 bit code. The error message basically says that you told it to build a 32bit application but supplied it a 64 bit library. You need to fix one or the other.

Comment: Ok I changed every variable to 32 bit but It still doesn't see the dlls I included.

Comment: Are the dlls in the same folder as your executable? Or at least in on of the folders in your windows PATH variable?

Comment: yes they are in the same folder as PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

for me (visual studio 13 express) worked to change from the vc11 directory to the vc 10 directory.